# use fq query instead q query , but it isn't work

Tags: solr, lucene

i have a query . because it only need filter data and  it need't score  but is not work.

```
    public static void testFqQuery()throws Exception{
    SolrQuery sq=new SolrQuery();
    sq.addFilterQuery("rowkey:2d8cf7bc5fb9ef9b7780a76f9b8c7c1a");
    QueryResponse response = sc.query(sq);
    SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
    System.out.println("hits："+results.getNumFound());
    for(SolrDocument sd:results){
        System.out.println(sd.get("rowkey"));
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: are you getting any specific error? Please paste actual code over image

Comment: @prasun it is no error, but it is also no result , you can try in you environment .

Answer (score 1):

I believe you still need a `q` value for the filter query to work. So you would have to do something like this:

`sq.setQuery("*:*");`

Which makes sense if you think about it, because you're telling Solr, "I want all records that match this filter."

Comment: You are right. As to be [read in the reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser): q - Defines a query using standard query syntax. This parameter is mandatory.